# Unable to Login to Website using request Library

Tags: python, request

```
import requests
login_data = {
        'j_username': '#',
        'j_password':'#'
        }

headers = {
        'User-Agent':'Chrome/70.0.3538.110'
        }
 url ="https://alm.vodafone.com/qcbin/rest/domains/EVO/projects/EVO_Automation_New/defect"
    login_url = "https://alm.vodafone.com/qcbin/rest/domains/EVO/projects/EVO_Automation_New/defect?login-form-required=y"
    r = C.get(login_url)
    tst = C.post(login_url,params=login_data,allow_redirects=True) 
    print("------",tst.status_code)
    resp = C.get(url)
    print("Second",resp.text)
    print(resp.status_code)
```

Comment: Hi @akshay, Do you get any errors when you run the above code? If so, please share the full `Traceback` error message. Also, what is the purpose of the `url` variable? and I do not see any definition for `C` variable either.

Comment: This url *"https://alm.vodafone.com"* uses `javascript` to perform login. `Requests` can't execute `javascript`.

Comment: @stovff thanx , so any idea how should i solve this issue

Comment: @amanb the variable C is for session creation. And variable URL is used after the successfully  logged in  to website , the error shows 401 authentication error

Comment: Why use a special variable 'C'? You could simple use request sessions. Moreover, its a very vague variable name. Try a variable name like `req_sess` which is more descriptive and include a definition for it in the code above. If you are using requests sessions, you must import it as well.

Comment: @amanb The problem here is about not able authente using request library, the error shows 401